# How to connect celery to rabbitMQ using SSL

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I'm trying to connect celery with a rabbitMQ broker using SSL certificates.

This is the code:

```
from celery import Celery
import ssl

broker_uri = 'amqp://user:pwd@server:5672/vhost'

certs_conf = {
    "ca_certs": "/certs/serverca/cacert.pem",
    "certfile": "/certs/client/rabbit-cert.pem",
    "keyfile": "/certs/client/rabbit-key.pem",
    "cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
}

app = Celery('tasks', broker=broker_uri)
app.conf.update(BROKER_USE_SSL=certs_conf)

app.send_task('task.name', [{'a': 1}])
```

When I try to execute this code i get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\functional.py", line 36, in __call__
    return self.__value__
AttributeError: 'ChannelPromise' object has no attribute '__value__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_send_task.py", line 44, in <module>
    app.send_task('task.name', [message])
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\celery\app\base.py", line 737, in send_task
    amqp.send_task_message(P, name, message, **options)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\celery\app\amqp.py", line 558, in send_task_message
    **properties
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\kombu\messaging.py", line 181, in publish
    exchange_name, declare,
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 494, in _ensured
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\kombu\messaging.py", line 187, in _publish
    channel = self.channel
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\kombu\messaging.py", line 209, in _get_channel
    channel = self._channel = channel()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\functional.py", line 38, in __call__
    value = self.__value__ = self.__contract__()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\kombu\messaging.py", line 224, in <lambda>
    channel = ChannelPromise(lambda: connection.default_channel)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 819, in default_channel
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 405, in ensure_connection
    callback)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\functional.py", line 333, in retry_over_time
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 261, in connect
    return self.connection
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 802, in connection
    self._connection = self._establish_connection()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 757, in _establish_connection
    conn = self.transport.establish_connection()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\kombu\transport\pyamqp.py", line 130, in establish_connection
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 288, in connect
    self.drain_events(timeout=self.connect_timeout)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 471, in drain_events
    while not self.blocking_read(timeout):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 477, in blocking_read
    return self.on_inbound_frame(frame)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\amqp\method_framing.py", line 55, in on_frame
    callback(channel, method_sig, buf, None)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 481, in on_inbound_method
    method_sig, payload, content,
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\amqp\abstract_channel.py", line 128, in dispatch_method
    listener(*args)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\amqp\connection.py", line 368, in _on_start
    b", ".join(self.mechanisms).decode()))
amqp.exceptions.ConnectionError: Couldn't find appropriate auth mechanism (can offer: AMQPLAIN, PLAIN; available: EXTERNAL)
```

Executing the same code without the ssl configuration works just well. What I'm missing?

I can send messages to the broker using pika configured with SSL, but I can't manage to properly configure Celery to send messages to the same broker with SSL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your question is answered please accept the answer, else just bring more details.

Answer (score 1):

Your server may already support SSL client authentication if it's offering the EXTERNAL authentication mechanism. For the Celery client however you need an additional configuration option to use EXTERNAL (i.e. SSL) authentication:

```
app.conf.broker_login_method = 'EXTERNAL'
```

For completeness, a valid celery configuration snippet would look like:

```
...
import ssl

app = Celery("some_name")

app.conf.broker_url = 'amqps://rabbitmq.example.com:5671/vhostname'

app.conf.broker_use_ssl = {
  'keyfile': r'C:\path\to\private\box1-nopass.key.pem',
  'certfile': r'C:\path\to\certs\box1.cert.pem',
  'ca_certs': r'C:\path\to\ca-chain.cert.pem',
  'cert_reqs': ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
}

app.conf.broker_login_method = 'EXTERNAL'
...
```

Note, there's no username:password in the `broker_url` as the username is determined by attributes of the client certificate (and the user must be pre-existing on the RabbitMQ server, configured with "no password") and the default SSL port is 5671 (not 5672).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the setting:

```
broker_use_ssl=True
```

You can also use the broker url starting with **amqps://...**

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable this plugin: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-auth-mechanism-ssl
and add following config to /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf

```
auth_mechanisms.1 = PLAIN
auth_mechanisms.2 = AMQPLAIN
auth_mechanisms.3 = EXTERNAL
```

if you only want the ssl connection, then add EXTERNAL only.